# How can i succesfully convert to a spefic Time and use .TotalDays?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, type-conversion

By Input i mean Console.ReadLine() and the way it got changed.

I tried to make a code that could count the days that the User inputed left in the same Year.
After that it should it should loop through the for loop.
This is what it should do.

The Output should be: The difference between the two Inputs, the amount of days it takes to end the year with the first Input in mind subtract that with the total amount and if it is more then 360 it should output the amount and subtract it with 360 so long until the it is under 360.

My Current Output is: 0 Days when numberOfDays is Outputed and when NumberOfDays2 is outputed the Output is 363.

My Problem is that i dont know what exactly the problem is in my Code.
It would be a great help if someone could explain to me where the Problem is or what the root of the Problem is.
Rightnow im very confused do to the comparison with my other code i made where parts like (.TotalDays) perfectly worked.
I would like to know why it doesnt work because in theory it should work.

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Input and Visual
            Console.WriteLine("write here Beginning");
            Console.Write("Day: ");
            string FirstDay = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Month:");
            string StillFirstDay = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Year:");
            string Still_FirstDay = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Beginn: " + FirstDay + "." + StillFirstDay + "." + Still_FirstDay);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("write here End ");
            Console.Write("Day: ");
            string LastDay = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Monat:");
            string StillLastDay = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Jahr:");
            string Still_LastDay = Console.ReadLine();

            //Prepare

            int input = 0;
            int IFirstDay = 1;
            int IStillFirstDay = 1;
            int IStill_FirstDay = 1;
            int ILastDay = 1;
            int IStillLastDay = 1;
            int IStill_LastDay = 1;

            JustforConversion(FirstDay, input, IFirstDay);
            JustforConversion(StillFirstDay, input, IStillFirstDay);
            JustforConversion(Still_FirstDay, input, IStill_FirstDay);
            JustforConversion(LastDay, input, ILastDay);
            JustforConversion(StillLastDay, input, IStillLastDay);
            JustforConversion(Still_LastDay, input, IStill_LastDay);

            DateTime date1 = new DateTime(IStill_LastDay, IStillLastDay, ILastDay);
            DateTime date2 = new DateTime(IStill_FirstDay, IStillFirstDay, IFirstDay);
            var numberOfDays = (date2 - date1).TotalDays;
            Console.WriteLine(numberOfDays);
            int Year = IStill_FirstDay - IStill_LastDay;
            DateTime date3 = new DateTime(IStillFirstDay, 12, 30);
            var numberOfDays1 = (date3 - date2).Days;
            Console.WriteLine(numberOfDays1);
            var numberOfDays2 = numberOfDays - numberOfDays1;
                        
            Console.WriteLine("In Year 1 there were " +numberOfDays1+" Days.");

            for (int i = 2; i <= Year; i++)
                {
                    if (numberOfDays2 > 360)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("In Year " + i + " there were " + numberOfDays2 + " Days.");
                        numberOfDays2 -= 360;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(numberOfDays2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void JustforConversion(string Converted,int Zero,int Complete_Convert)
        {
            while (int.TryParse(Converted, out Zero))
            {
                Complete_Convert = Convert.ToInt32(Converted);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which problem do you have with the code? Can you give some sample input, expected and observed output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As @KlausGütter says, what are the errors you are seeing? And what is it that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: The Problem im having is that the output is wrong. And the User Input doesnt affect the Output. Im expecting Total Days then how many days it takes to reach the end of the year  and then a record for every year when there is more days. A Output that often happens is: 0 Days, 363Days. I hope that will help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information. Can you please give a very concrete example of input, expected output and observed output so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: You should get an automatic zero for your variable names alone: Day --> `FirstDay` | Month --> `StillFirstDay` | Year --> `Still_FirstDay`

Comment: Thank you for your friendly Reminder i just didnt had a good idea for days, months and Years. I didnt want them to be called Year1, Year 2, Month1, Month2, Day1, Day2.

Comment: Those names would have been way better!

Comment: I will do just a suggestion. Before going into bigger pieces of code, work on small pieces. Please, please, study your JustforConversion() method. What a useless code, don't you think? Do you have any idea why you used while() there? What is the point? If you can't simply fix that part, the rest would be a giant problem for you.

Comment: Although it doesn't directly effect your code, naming conventions are worth reading.

Comment: Im going to do just that

Answer (score 0):

Your `JustforConversion()` method has so many things wrong with it, but the biggest problem is that it doesn't actually "return" anything. `ints` are passed "by value", which means a copy is made; the original variable is NOT changed after the call to `JustforConversion()`.

It looks like you were expecting the "Ixxx" variables to have valid integers in them after the calls. You'd need to declare that parameter as an `out` parameter for this to work:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string FirstDay = "10";
    int IFirstDay = 1;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Before JustforConversion():");
    Console.WriteLine("IFirstDay = " + IFirstDay);
    
    JustforConversion(FirstDay, out IFirstDay);
    
    Console.WriteLine("After JustforConversion():");
    Console.WriteLine("IFirstDay = " + IFirstDay);
  }

  static void JustforConversion(string Converted, out int IConverted)
  {
    IConverted = int.Parse(Converted);
  }
```

Output:

```
Before JustforConversion():
IFirstDay = 1
After JustforConversion():
IFirstDay = 10
```

Comment: string FirstDay = "hello";

Comment: @CetinBasoz That'll definitely cause a problem, yes. This post is just solving the FIRST problem of many...

Comment: thank you so much i never thought of rethinking my Method. This was such a help.

Comment: I wanted to make things separately from my main Code to test it out and search for mistakes before hand and solve problems in another Code so that i can implement it without much worries. So thank you very much.